# ERROR Host does not support virtualization type 'hvm

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

hello I have a problem in installing vm on KVM using libvirt(virsh install -)

```
sudo virt-install -n ccnx1 -r 512 --vcpus=1 --os-type=linux --accelerate --nographics -v -l ~/ubuntu-12.04.5-alternate-i386.iso --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/test.img,size=5 -x "console=ttyS0"
```

The output of console "ERROR    Host does not support virtualization type 'hvm' "

Before installing qemu 1.2.0, (for using qemu-img) installing VM works well, but after installing qemu, above output was generated

My kvm version is `'QEMU emulator version 1.0 (qemu-kvm-1.0)'`

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because Virtualization is not enabled in the BIOS.

Comment: Or the system processor does not have hardware-assisted virtualization support.

Comment: and if it is supported and the kernel modules are loaded?